# What Causes Windows 7 Display To Dim While Keyboard and Mouse Are Active?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, display-settings

I am working with two Windows 7 desktop computers, both of which have a unique problem I have not seen before. (To reiterate, these are not laptop computers; they have no battery and hence no battery settings that can be set.) One of the computers has a brand new monitor, and the other has a monitor that I have no reason to believe is malfunctioning.

Please be advised that this dimming is coming while the keyboard and mouse are active. I do believe -- please correct if I'm wrong -- that active keyboard and mouse will bring a dimmed or display shutdown computer out of those states with an active keyboard and/or mouse.

I can be working right along using the keyboard and mouse. All of a sudden, the display dims for no apparent reason. The display will not brighten back up with vigorous mouse movement.

I have looked at articles like [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/turning-off-windows-7-auto-dimming-on-desktop/4954ba46-27a3-4415-9f00-d76056694334), but I thought displays turned back on with keyboard/mouse activity, let alone never dim when there was mouse/keyboard activity already present.

My question is what setting or settings might be causing this? To the best of my knowledge no one has installed or set a screen saver that might be causing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my screen dim on a desktop installation of Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/71714)

Comment: (1) In Control Panel / Power Options/ Select a power plan, have you set it to High performance? (2) What exact models are the concerned computers & display adapters? (3) If the display adapters came with configuration software, do they have any power options?

Comment: From @Nathan: Are you using a standard keyboard (ie no function keys or hotkeys)? I have seen strange behavior when Windows doesn't install a function/hotkey keyboard correctly and you may be inadvertently triggering a dim monitor function.

Comment: @fixer1234 These are pretty vanilla computers with standard Lenovo keyboard. The users are not sophisticated that they would be mapping keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might solve your problems:

> "Auto dim or also referred to as Smart Dimmer in Windows 7 is
>   available in computer systems that have the hardware which supports
>   this feature.   Please see the troubleshooting steps below that would
>   help resolve your issue.
>
> 1. Open Power Options by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security, and then clicking Power
>      Options.
> 2. Under the current power plan, click Change plan settings.
> 3. On the Change settings for the plan page, click on Change advanced power settings.
> 4. In Advanced settings, scroll down the menu, click on Display and see if you find the dim feature listed here. You may change the
>      settings for Auto dim if present under display, accordingly to as you
>      want."

The text above is quoted from Microsoft Answers:
[Turning off Windows 7 auto-dimming on desktop](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/turning-off-windows-7-auto-dimming-on-desktop/4954ba46-27a3-4415-9f00-d76056694334)

Comment: I can't get to this computer for a while, but I'll get to it before 7 days are up, and try it out. You could have hit on it.

Comment: I think that feature might be hardware dependent, so maybe some weird drivers or software causing it not to work properly. Since it's an "always plugged in desktop computer", I guess this feature is of no interest what so ever. Hope it helps :)